# mime-mail and xmlhtml have conflicting dependencies

Tags: haskell, virtual-machine, dependency-management, cabal

I believe am running the latest Haskell platform, as of this writing. GHC version is 7.6.3. Cabal-install version is 1.16.0.2 and cabal version is 1.16.0. This is running on a virtualbox machine running Ubuntu 14.04.2.

Here is my problem. I have an application that has dependencies on both mime-mail and xmlhtml. Both of these packages have a dependency on blaze-builder. When I install these two packages, in either order, installing the second one complains that it might break the other one, and it does. Running cabal configure complains that blaze-builder is missing and is required by whichever package (mime-mail or xmlhtml) that I installed later.

Now here is the weird part. This builds fine, with some warnings, on a physical server running the same versions of GHC and cabal. It is also running the same version of Ubuntu. The only difference that I can see is that the one that works is a physical machine and the one that doesn't is a virtualbox machine.

No, I am not building in a sandbox. I have been reading about sandboxes, but I don't think it will be of help here since the conflicting dependent packages are in the same application.

My problem is compounded by the fact that this physical machine is going away. Therefore, I need to get this development environment running on my local VM.

Any suggestions of where to look next?

Dave Smith

Comment: By all means do build in a sandbox. Also, don't use the Haskell platform. Install just the compiler and cabal. You may also want to try [stack](https://www.stackage.org/).

Answer (score 1):

On the advice of n.m., I created a new VM and installed only GHC and cabal, i.e. not the full haskell-platform package. I was not able, in this environment to create a sandbox. The command `cabal sandbox init` failed with an error about not recognizing the sandbox command.

However, after installing libpq-dev to fix the problem with installing the haskell library for client PostgreSQL, I am able to build my application without error.

I did do one more thing differently. Instead of doing a `cabal configure` and then installing all of the missing dependencies myself, I did a `cabal install --only-dependencies` and let cabal decide which dependencies to install in which order.

So I now have a working development environment for this application, but I am left with one question.

What did the Haskell platform install do that caused this problem and why was it better to install just the compiler and cabal? OK, two questions. When might I want to install the entire Haskell platform package?

Thanks for the help!

Dave

Comment: The "one more thing differently" is probably what did it. By installing all the dependencies at once, the solver was able to look for a solution that satisfied them simultaneously, instead of conflicting "local optima" that were incompatible with other things in your set.

Comment: Also note that the ubuntu haskell platform is quite out of date compared to the development of the Haskell ecosystem as a whole...  If its working fine for you so far thats good, but the last HP release with the 7.6 series was in 2013. So generally given an older base, you're more likely to run into other dep issues as libraries move it out of their window of support...